# How can I change the hight of the left and right border of the block quote and connect the border to another div?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

[Block Quote Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUKzu.png)

I'm trying to make my blockquote look like the image attached. I have the top and bottom gradients down, but I'm stuck on the left and right borders and I'm not sure how to round the quotations more. Also, I was wondering how to make a line to the right that connects to the picture. Thanks for the help!

Here's what I have so far

```css
/*-------Testimonial Section Styles---------*/

section#testimonial-section {
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}


/*------Block Quote Sttyles-------*/

.testimonial-paragraph-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.testimonial-border {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 117px;
  float: left;
}

blockquote {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 36px 50px;
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  /* gradient shining border */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(108, 178, 61, 1) 100%, rgba(108, 178, 61, 1) 100%, rgba(108, 178, 61, 1) 100%), linear-gradient(to left, rgba(108, 178, 61, 1) 100%, rgba(108, 178, 61, 1) 100%, rgba(108, 178, 61, 1) 100%);
  background-size: 90% 5px;
  background-position: 100% 0%, -510% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-left: 5px solid rgba(108, 178, 61, 1);
  border-right: 5px solid rgba(108, 178, 61, 1);
}

cite {
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 100px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

blockquote::before,
article blockquote::after {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 25px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #61a036;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

blockquote::before {
  right: 100%;
}

blockquote::after {
  left: 100%;
}

blockquote p {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 28px;
  color: #61a036;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

blockquote p::before {
  top: 0;
  left: -33px;
  color: #61a036;
  content: '“';
  font-size: 10em;
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: -3px 0 #000;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

blockquote p::after {
  right: 16px;
  color: #61a036;
  content: '”';
  bottom: -32px;
  font-size: 10em;
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 3px 0 #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section id="testimonial-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
        <div class="testimonial-wrapper">
          <div id="testimonial-border" class="testimonial-paragraph-wrapper">
            <blockquote>
              <p class="blockquote-text">My son had to go to the doctor’s office and my insurance didn’t pay for some of it, and rent was due ... then I looked at the calendar...I was going to be getting a big payment from FusionCash in only 3 more days, straight to my PayPal®
                account!</p>
              <cite>- John Hughes of Grants Pass, OR</cite>
            </blockquote>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
        <div class="testimonial-img-wrapper">
          <img class=" testimonial-img" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/alexscloud1234/image/upload/c_scale,w_200/v1516656363/ryan-fields-328391_lxjslk.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: For the left and right borders, I would import a better looking quotation image icon with white background https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=quotation&i=1247733 , place it above the corners of the box to hide the left/right borders. To connect the quote and the image you could absolute position a `<hr>` element. And then your baby image would need a border and some padding to match your reference image. This is ofcourse only my suggestion depends on if you need responsiveness or how dyanamic this layout would be~

Answer (score 0):

The connecting line can easily be done with flexbox, just use a pseudo element on your container and adjust the position with `order`.

(I took the bootstrap out of the equation, to simplify things... adapt as needed)

```css
/*-------Testimonial Section Styles---------*/
#testimonial-section{
  margin:20px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  position:relative;
}

#testimonial-section:before{
  content:"";
  height:4px;
  flex:1 1 10%;
  background:#61a036;
}
.testimonial-img{
  flex:1 1 20%;
  border:4px solid #61a036;
  border-radius:50%; padding:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
}

#testimonial-section blockquote{
  margin:0;
  border:4px solid #61a036;
  flex:1 1 70%;
  position:relative;
  color: #61a036;
  font-size:1.5em;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  order:-1;
}

#testimonial-section blockquote:before, #testimonial-section blockquote:after{
  text-align:center;
  background:white;
  position:absolute;
  font-size:8rem;
  width:4rem; height:5rem;
}
#testimonial-section blockquote:before{
  content:"“";
  top:-2rem;
  left:-2rem;
}
#testimonial-section blockquote:after{
  content:"”";
  bottom:-2rem;
  right:-2rem;
}

.blockquote-text{
  padding:1em;
}

cite{
  font-size:1rem;
  position:relative;
  top:0.5rem;
  background:white;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<section id="testimonial-section">
  <blockquote>
    <p class="blockquote-text">My son had to go to the doctor’s office and my insurance didn’t pay for some of it, and rent was due ... then I looked at the calendar...I was going to be getting a big payment from FusionCash in only 3 more days, straight to my PayPal® account!</p>
    <cite>- John Hughes of Grants Pass, OR</cite>
  </blockquote>

  <img class="testimonial-img" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/alexscloud1234/image/upload/c_scale,w_200/v1516656363/ryan-fields-328391_lxjslk.png">
</section>
```

The rest should be just positioning.